# Sage Pay on Magento and don't send email

Tags: email, magento, cart, opayo

We use Magento (version 1.9.1.0). 
Since installing SagePay via ebizmarts plugin we have had some ongoing issues with sending emails. The abandoned cart no longer sends regular emails. What could be the reason?
Who faced such problem please reply. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

If use extensions to send a mail there is chances of not getting abandoned cart email. so try to send email with the mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I solved the problem. The developers of the extensions "SagePay" suggested. It was necessary to additionally install the latest version of the extension MageMonkey. Current version 1.2.3.
Maybe someone will need this solution.